# Netty 4.0.0_CR7: Chunked[Byte]Input does not always get drained completely

Tags: java, netty

Env: Win 7 / JRE 1.6.0_45 / Netty 4.0.0_CR7

My client app is streaming files to a TCP server using an implementation of ChunkedByteInput. A typical file of 10 MB size is transferred in chunks of 20 kB each, resulting in some 500 chunks.

The TCP connection is set up beforehand (GUI elements such as the Upload button get enabled after the connection is established) and not closed afterwards either. Instead, the ChunkedByteInput implementation representing a single file prepends a header chunk containing file name and size and appends a footer chunk with the file's MD5 hash.

Normally, all is well. But in random cases (10-20%), transfer stops after some arbitrary chunk (ChunkedInput.readChunk() does not get called anymore). As a workaround, I simply write the incomplete input to the Channel again after some extended period (say 5 sec) of inactivity is detected, and transfer resumes and completes normally. But this clearly is a dirty hack.

Any idea what causes this behavior?

**Edit**: Here is the link to the related issue on Github:
https://github.com/netty/netty/issues/1506

Comment: The issue could not be reproduced in isolation and was solved by upgrading to Netty 4.0.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by upgrading to Netty 4.0.1